# save html page from the server by URL with no changes - get the exact copy, the clone

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

Let's say I have a URL `http://example.com/path/to/document.html`

That's the html document, the file, that has no external css or js.
If I open it in Google Chrome and save it with `Ctrl+S` locally, the content is changed. The content of that html file starts with `<!-- saved from url=` which is not I want at all. I need to get the exact html document, even spaces count.

The second option is to copy it with `Ctrl+U`  (View Source), Select All and paste it into new document, save it and rename it. This is better, however spaces, tabs and end of file will be different depending on what operation system I'm using.

I need the exact copy of that html file - byte to byte.
How to make it?

This is a practical question as I need slightly modify that document.

I'm sorry there is no any source code in my question, but this question is about web developing.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

P.S. Of course that document could be generated by `php` or whatever, the part of the code can be even extracted from the db, but not in my case. I know that's a plain file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd delete the  comment after saving from Chrome, use wget in a linux environment, or open the page as an InputStream in Java. Do all three, run a diff, and if two arrived identical assume that's the file on the server.

Why do you need a byte-for-byte copy of the file on the server anyway, and why can't you ftp the file?  There is always the chance that the server will serve different html files depending on your user-agent, but there are other tools which may be better than Chrome for getting your copy and many can spoof a user-agent as well.